# Why doesn't my PHP code return any results?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When running this PHP code it works, but doesn't return any results - can anyone tell me why please?  I have tried checking the code, but as it runs it's not that obvious. So I think it has a problem with the echoing SQL statement.

```
  <!doctype html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
     <title>Bed & Breakfast</title>
    <style type = "text/css">
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form style = "text-align:center; margin-top:200px;"method="POST" action ="">
            <span> Hotel Venue<span><input style ="margin-left:20px;" type="number" Name ="HotelVenueRef"/><br/><br/><br/>
            <input style = "margin-left:100px;" type='submit' value='HotelVenueRef' Name ="HotelVenueRef"/>
        </form>

        <?php
            if (isset($_POST['HotelVenueRef']))
            {
            require_once 'connecttodatabase.php'; 



        $sql=" select * from`B&B` where Hotel_Venue_ref =" .$_POST['HotelVenueRef'];

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {


        echo'
        <td align="center">'.$row['Delegate_Student_uid'] .' </td>';

        echo'
        <td align="center">'.$row['Name'] .' </td>';

        echo'
        <td align="center">'.$row['Event_uid'] .' </td>';

        echo'
        <td align="center">'.$row['Hotel_Venue_ref'] .' </td>';


        }
}
?>
</body>
</head>
```

I know about the injection vulnerability, that's not a problem at the moment. Just need to get it working for now.

Comment: First, try setting action in your form tag to the correct URL for your code

Comment: *"Why doesn't this code work"* - You tell us http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: Plus, why do you have 2x `Name ="HotelVenueRef"` and `type="number"` with no input and just a span?

Comment: Your SQL code has a security vulnerability in it - SQL injection. Use parameterisation with a modern library (PDO/mysql, mysqli) to fix that.

Comment: I know about injection thats not a problem atm just need to get it working for now

Comment: Take a look at PDO prepared statements. This will help prevent errors in your SQL statements and also protect your database from injection attacks. Something like $statement = $db->prepare(" select * from`B&B` where Hotel_Venue_ref = :ref"); $statement->bindParam(":ref", $_POST['HotelVenueRef'], PDO::PARAM_STR).

Comment: Someone gave you an answer below, but I disagree with what they posted. Read the comments that "I" have left everywhere.

Comment: Try swapping this in: `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. It's possible your connection is not working, but my guess is the query has failed - let's see why.

Comment: `<span> Hotel Venue<span><input style ="margin-left:20px;" type="number" Name ="HotelVenueRef"/><br/><br/><br/> <input style = "margin-left:100px;" type='submit' value='HotelVenueRef' Name ="HotelVenueRef"/>` that whole block is wrong.

Comment: Why are my comments fallen to deaf ears?

Comment: Sorry @Fred, they had my fingers in them. La la la! `/me hums to self`

Comment: @halfer Oh, the ♫ lah-lah-lah ♫? Yeah, some need to go to Karaoke more often.

Comment: Yes, I should have added some musical notes! ♫♫

Comment: @halfer Ah gee, thanks! I'll get my banjo and mandolin ♫ ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql=" select * from `B&B` where Hotel_Venue_ref =  '" . mysql_escape_string($_POST['HotelVenueRef']) . "'");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);        
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}
```

Add this code before while statement

Comment: Sorry answering through app

Comment: [See this Meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165505), in particular the bit about "posting from a cell phone". Thanks for fixing. (The quotes on your first line of code are mismatched, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that your issue is a result of the fact that you have 2 input elements with the same name (HotelVenueRef).

Here's your form, I've cleaned up the formatting and taken out some style attributes because they're irrelevant to the problem and it's cleaner without them. I've also lower-cased all attribute names (because consistency is key!!)

```
<form "method="POST" action ="">
    <span>Hotel Venue<span>
    <input type="number" name="HotelVenueRef"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="HotelVenueRef" name="HotelVenueRef"/>
</form>
```

The issue is that you have both an `<input type="number"/>` *and* an `<input type="submit"/>` that have the same name.

When a form submits to PHP, the `$_POST` array is populated with key-value pairs, where the key is based off the `name` attribute of the html input element, and the value is the value of that input.

Let's say you set the number input to have a value of 5, and then submit the form.

PHP will now auto-generate the `$_POST` array. Behind the scenes, it does something like

```
$_POST['HotelVenueRef'] = 5;
```

Based off of the value in the number input. Then it goes and does something like

```
$_POST['HotelVenueRef'] = 'HotelVenueRef';
```

This is the part you haven't noticed! The submit button also submits to PHP as part of the form, and its value now overwrites the value you're interested in.

The reason you're not getting any results is that your query resolves to look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `B&B` WHERE `Hotel_Venue_ref`='HotelVenueRef'
```

With the value of the submit button, instead of the value of the number input.

You can solve your problem by removing the "name" attribute on the submit button, which will prevent its value from submitting to PHP along with the rest of the form. You also have the option of renaming your submit button.

Comment: *"I have a feeling that your issue is a result of the fact that you have 2 input elements with the same name (HotelVenueRef)."* - All those comments about that were ignored. Ones I left the OP; **twice**, if not **thrice**.

Comment: That's true! I didn't read through all the comments before posting away.

Comment: It's not your fault. I was just saying ;-) Good explanation though.